# How to match the PNG image size between manually executing a chunk and knitting a file using knitr and ggsave

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, knitr

I have knitted a PDF using 'knitr' package. It also saves a PNG file in the directory using 'ggsave'.

- When the PNG file is generated manually from chunk

  - Bar Chart: PNG file size is 13.3 kb and dimensions are 1008 x 1008.
- When the PNG file is generated during the knitting process, using "Ctrl +Shift +K"

  - Bar Chart: PNG file size is 11.4 kb and dimensions are 936 x 647.

**What should I do so that PNG files generated in both cases should have same size and dimensions?** If possible, I would prefer that the output to be 13.3 kb in both situations.

I have added code for minimum reproducible example. Please save it as a ".Rmd" File for generating PNG and PDF.

Thank You

- The YAML Header of the File to generate PDF (Surround it by Triple Dashes)

```yaml
title: "Image Size Mismatch"
output: pdf_document
```

- R Code for Loading Packages, generating a Bar Chart, and saving it as PNG.

**EDIT: Smaller Code Example**

```r
# Packages
library("knitr")
library("ggplot2")

# Data
hh <- data.frame(groups = factor(c("No", "Yes", NA)), n = c(3843, 856, 19))

# Create Chart
pp <- ggplot(data = hh, aes(x = groups, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

# Save Image
ggsave("Bar.png", plot = pp, device = "png", dpi = 144)
```

**Older Example:** It had some unnecessary code.

```r
# Packages
library("knitr")
library("dplyr")
library("tibble")
library("ggplot2")

# Data
hh <- tibble(groups = factor(c("No", "Yes", NA)), n = c(3843, 856, 19))
loc_png <- "Pie.png"

# Create Pie Chart
pp <- ggplot(data = hh, aes(x = '', y = n, fill = groups)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 1, color = "white") +
    coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
    # Add Text Labels
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(groups, "\n", n)),
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    # Theme and Labs
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
          legend.position = 'none', axis.text = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
    labs(title = "Pie")

# Save Image
ggsave(loc_png, plot = pp, device = "png", dpi = 144)
# Problem: 
# Manual Chunk Execution: Output File: Size 32.5 kb, Dimension 1008 x 1008
# Knit "Ctrl +Shift +K" : Output File: Size 22.4 kb, Dimension 936 x 647
```

Comment: Honestly, your "minimum" example needs 4 imports and a call to define the background color? Btw, you can control the size of the png within the `ggsave` call and you can find some information on size within the knitted document here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html

Comment: @Bernhard 'dplyr' is not required probably and can be dropped. However other 3 are needed. My question is about 'same code should generate same output in both circumstances'. I have looked at that page but it did not clarify my issue. Still, Thank You for your time.

Comment: @Bernhard On 2nd thought, you are right, I could have decreased the required code when all I am interested in difference of image sizes. Sorry, will do that.

Comment: You can state the size of a PNG within the call to `ggsave` and the pic size within the knitted document via the `fig.dim` option in RMarkdown. If you set both to the same size and maybe adjust the `dpi` in the `ggsave` call so it matches your document's dpi, how does that not help with your problem?

Comment: @Bernhard, Thank You. Understood finally !! `ggsave` takes the size from window which turned out to be (6.3 inch) different from knitr default (7 inch). When executing the chunk manually, knitr setting is used (7). However, during knitting ggsave supplies the R window size (6.3) which overrides the knitr defult. Suppllying the value in ggsave call did resolve my problem as you have suggested. If you write your comment as answer, I will accept it, otherwise I will right it myself tomorrow. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take control over how large and with which aspect ratio a plot is drawn both in RMarkdown as well as with `ggsave`. For your purpose, you'll want to set both to the same values.

Adjusting plot size and thereby aspect ratio are described in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html ,  the proper use of `ggsave` in `help("ggsave")`.

The following minimal example is valid Rmd and uses both options from within the same file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, fig.dim = c(5, 3)}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))

ggsave("test.png", width = 5, height = 3, units = "in")
```
````

Honestly, I do not know, how many dots per inch (dpi) are used in the knitted document, my example appears to be written as a vector file, but if needed, that could also easily be adapted in the call of `ggsave`. Be the call of `ggsave` within the Rmd or outside of it.